# LDAP3 Query will not return login name

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

The following ldap3 query in py 3.5.3

```
base_dn = 'OU=Groups,OU=[SOME0U],OU=[ANOTHEROU],DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM'
query_filter = '(&(objectCategory=*)(cn=AD_GROUP_NAME))'
attrs=['member']
conn.search(base_dn,query_filter,search_scope=ldap3.SUBTREE, attributes=attrs, size_limit=10) 
entry = conn.entries[0]
```

returns

```
DN: CN=AD_GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=SOMEOU,OU=ANOTHEROU,DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM - STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2017-12-19T07:04:45.583177

    member: CN=SASQUACH IS REAL,OU=ONEMOREOU,OU=Users,OU=SOMEOU,OU=ANOTHEROU,DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM

            CN=AD_GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=SOMEOU,OU=ANOTHEROU,DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM
```

I've tried userPrincipalName, email, givenName,sAMAccountName in the attrs to return, no dice.

I'm needing ***ONLY*** the login names  to parse into a list (csv) for use elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: the sAMAccountname is the typical login name for a user in LDAP.

Comment: Did you get it working? I am pulling my hair not being able to get the value of sAMAccountName

Answer (score 0):

IF I UNDERSTAND what you are trying to accomplish.

You need the full dn for the group.

```
base_dn = 'CN=Users,DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM'
query_filter = '(memberOf=CN=YOUR_GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=[SOME0U],OU=[ANOTHEROU],DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM)'
attrs=['sAMAccountName']
results = (base_dn,query_filter,search_scope=ldap3.SUBTREE, attributes=attrs, size_limit=10)  
print results
```

Comment: I get "invalid filter" when trying the full DN:   base_dn = 'CN=GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=UNIT,OU=REGION,DC=big,DC=foot,DC=com'    query_filter = '(memberOf=CN=GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=UNIT,OU=REGION,DC=big,DC=foot,DC=com) )'

Comment: same error with: base_dn = 'CN=Users,DC=big,DC=foot,DC=com'

Comment: Also tried   query_filter = '(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=SOME_OU,OU=ANOTHER_OUDC=big,DC=foot,DC=com)) % cn'

Comment: there is an extra parenth in my answer. (I just fixed it)(memberOf=CN=YOUR_GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=[SOME0U],OU=[ANOTHEROU],DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM)

Comment: Thanks for the update. So that returns just the group name...."DN: CN=GROUP_NAME,OU=Groups,OU=SOME_OU,OU=ANOTHER_OU,DC=BIG,DC=FOOT,DC=COM- STATUS: Read - READ TIME: 2017-12-21T13:15:55.817910    sAMAccountName: GROUP_NAME" I've also tried adding "memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=" but that again results in invalid filter.

Comment: The query appears to work. I would suggest you obtain a LDAP Browser like: http://directory.apache.org/studio/ and perform the search so we can see where it is failing.